# is there a good way to convert python bytes to a string and back?

Tags: python

I am looking for a good way to convert bytes to a python string and back, I have tried

```
Sample_bytes = some_way_to_get_bytes()
output_str = ""
for i in Sample_bytes:
   output_str += str(i) + "%"
```

then I would convert to bytes by:

```
output_bytes = b""
a = b""
for i in sample_str:
   if i == "%":
      output_bytes += a
      a = b""
   else:
      a += int(i).ConvertToBytes()
```

I used a hypothetical

```
int.ConvertToBytes()
```

function, is there any way to convert an int to bytes in python?

Comment: [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)?

Comment: There is `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()`, with optional encoding argument (UTF-8 by default).

Comment: ```bytes.decode``` takes a str arg/param

Comment: I could try that

Comment: would need to change my code a bit

Comment: it does not seem to work with the type of bytes I am using(zip files)

Comment: is there something that can convert ints to bytes?

Comment: @JordanSweetman `bytes.decode` takes *two* parameters, really: the bytes to decode and (optionally) the scheme used to decode them. While you can write `bytes.decode(b'...')`, usually you write `b'...'.decode()`. Your `zip` file, though, isn't just an encoded Unicode string. If you want to "decode" them, use the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module to decompress/unpack the files that are encoded as a stream of bytes.

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to figure out how to close one of these lol

Comment: @chepner, could you repost your comment as an answer, the mods will not let me close it if you do not…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bytes.decode` takes two parameters, really: the bytes to decode and (optionally) the scheme used to decode them. While you can write `bytes.decode(b'...')`, usually you write `b'...'.decode()`. Your zip file, though, isn't just an encoded Unicode string. If you want to "decode" them, use the `zipfile` module to decompress/unpack the files that are encoded as a stream of bytes.